# Cordova Can't find variable: NativeStorage

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic-framework

I had a project from about 7 months ago I was trying to rebuild. When I run it on ios I get the error "Can't find variable: NativeStorage" from the polyfills file. I tried to play with versions up and down but ended with no such luck

Cordova - Version 6.5
Ionic - Version 3.20.0

In the main service I have declared NativeStorage as any for use.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your call of the native storage plugin in ‍‍‍`$ionicPlatform.ready` because you have to be sure, that cordova and the pluginsystem are ready:
check [ionic.platform](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/utility/ionic.Platform/).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by getting latest right from git instead of npm